# Open button not hiding when side bar pops out

Tags: javascript, html, css

My side bar, when opened, pushes everything to the left. I just simply want to get rid of the open button when it does get pushed to the left. When the side bar pops out, the background image gets pushed to the left with the open button. I want the open button to disappear I click it and reappear when the margins are back to normal and the side bar is closed.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>IKC Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
    <div class="backgroundImg">
    <span class="openNav" id="openNav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    </div>
    <div id ="sideNav" class="sideNav">
        <a id='link' href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeButton" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a id='link' href="about.html">About<a>
        <a id='link' href="members.html">Members<a>
        <a id='link' href="services.html">Services<a>
        <a id='link' href="contactUs.html">Contact<a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.backgroundImg {
    background-image: url(blueMoutains.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: brightness(60%);
}

.openNav {
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: black;
}

.sideNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideNav a {
    color: #818181;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
}

.sideNav .closeButton {
    color: #818181;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 45vh;
    position: relative;
    left: 0vh;
    bottom: 25vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sideNav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sideNav {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .sideNav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}
```

Javascript

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "350px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "350px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `openNav` function, get the open button and hide it using styles:

```js
document.querySelector("#openNav").style.display = "none";
```

And show it again inside `closeNav`:

```js
document.querySelector("#openNav").style.display = "initial";
```

A demo:

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "350px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "350px";
    document.querySelector("#openNav").style.display = "none";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("sideNav").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0px";
    document.querySelector("#openNav").style.display = "initial";
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.backgroundImg {
    background-image: url(blueMoutains.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    filter: brightness(60%);
}

.openNav {
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    z-index: 0;
    color: black;
}

.sideNav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    width: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.sideNav a {
    color: #818181;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    display: block;
}

.sideNav .closeButton {
    color: #818181;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 45vh;
    position: relative;
    left: 0vh;
    bottom: 25vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.sideNav a:hover{
    color: white;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sideNav {
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    .sideNav a {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="backgroundImg">
        <span class="openNav" id="openNav" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
    </div>
    <div id ="sideNav" class="sideNav">
        <a id='link' href="javascript:void(0)" class="closeButton" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a id='link' href="about.html">About</a>
        <a id='link' href="members.html">Members</a>
        <a id='link' href="services.html">Services</a>
        <a id='link' href="contactUs.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
</div>
```